# How to generate XML (in String representation) in java

Tags: java, xml

I have defined a java class, but only need to output some of the fields of this class into an XML. The returned type must be a String. I first opted for the easiest way using a StringBuffer. However, when I tried to process the output String represenation, it failed. I think it is mostly likely because there are some characters that are not encoded in the UTF-8 in the input. Could someone tell me what is the best way to handle this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Give [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) a try.

**Quote:**

> Let's create an instance of Person and
>   populate its fields:

```
 Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
 joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
 joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
```

> Now, to convert it to
>   XML, all you have to do is make a
>   simple call to XStream:

```
String xml = xstream.toXML(joe)
```

> The resulting XML looks like this:
>
> ```
> <person>
>   <firstname>Joe</firstname> 
>   <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
>   <phone>
>     <code>123</code>
>     <number>1234-456</number>
>   </phone>
>   <fax>
>     <code>123</code>
>     <number>9999-999</number>
>   </fax> 
>   </person>
> ```
>
> It's that simple. Look at how clean the XML is.

Comment: Oh, my.  I've never seen this before, but it's cool as hell.  I'm bookmarking this.  Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) myself, but there are a lot of good third-party XML tools for Java out there.  The important things to remember are that 1) hand-rolling your own XML with `String` or `StringBuffer` or the like is the sort of thing that always comes back to bite you and 2) Java's built-in XML utilities are over-engineered and not at all pleasant to work with.  (Though they're still an improvement over constructing the XML string manually.)  Grabbing a good third-party package is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Java Architecture for XML Binding](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/) (or simply JAXB) - with annotations it should be extremely easy and elegant.

In the simplest case, all you have to do, is just add @XmlRootElement annotation to the bean you want to serialize into XML

```
@XmlRootElement
class Foo{
..
}
```

and marshall the bean into a formatted string

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE ); 
m.marshal(individual, writer);
```

[By default](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html), the Marshaller will use UTF-8 encoding when generating XML data to a java.io.OutputStream, or a java.io.Writer.