# Saving an arraylist to a file as XML

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

Is it possible to simply dump an ArrayList to an XML file?

I have an array-list which contains various types of message objects.

What I would like to do is save this to an XML file to keep a log.

What I have tried is this.

```
public void saveConversation()
    {
        FileOutputStream f_out;
        try {
            f_out = new  FileOutputStream("convo.txt");
            // Write object with ObjectOutputStream
            ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new  ObjectOutputStream (f_out);
            // Write object out to disk
            obj_out.writeObject (convo);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HunterCom.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
```

This works but the file created doesn't make much seance. I was wondering if there was a simple way to change this to readable XML?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024105/how-to-generate-xml-in-string-representation-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org), it is designed for exactly this task.